# AWS Cloudformation Bug: recursive lock because of recursive Import

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

A Cloudformation stack can get into a recursive lock following the next steps:

1. Setup CF without import values (and create stack)
2. Use same CF template to create soms output-values (and update stack)
3. Use `!importValue` (with output value created in step 2) in the same CF-template (and update stack)
4. Try to delete the stack

Answer (score 0):

I would not say a bug but a known issue from a couple of years. Refer to the answer below to fix your issue. 
[Delete export variable and help removing circular dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44371990/delete-export-variable-and-help-removing-circular-dependency?rq=1)

To answer in simple terms, perform the following in different steps: 
1. Remove import statements and use hardcoded values of the resources
2. Remove export statements
3. Delete your stack